# Mysql query to Laravel query Like %% Problem

Tags: mysql, laravel, search

```
SELECT tmsid, RIGHT(tmsid,6) AS max_number 
FROM tms_tables 
WHERE tmsid = (SELECT MAX(tmsid) 
               FROM tms_tables 
               WHERE tmsid LIKE '%1001%' )
```

How to convert this to Laravel?

[image]

If I do like that, I get an error

> A non-numeric value encountered

```
DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT tmsid, RIGHT(tmsid,6) 
    as max_number FROM tms_tables WHERE 
      tmsid=(SELECT MAX(tmsid) FROM tms_tables where tmsid LIKE '%1001%' )'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have wrapped your statement inside ('), you cannot use '%100%'. So wrap your statement using ("). Try below code

```
DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT tmsid, RIGHT(tmsid,6) as max_number FROM tms_tables WHERE tmsid=(SELECT MAX(tmsid) FROM tms_tables where tmsid LIKE '%1001%' )"));
```

Comment: Thanks Brother It's Working.. that mean invited comma is problem  (') and (")

Comment: It's working but when i use 'LIKE', '%1001%' variable replace to 1001 and $auth_dept_code = Auth::user()->dept_code; $auth_branch_code = Auth::user()->branch_code; $auth_code = $auth_dept_code.$auth_branch_code; $auth_code is 1001, variable ->where('tmsid', 'LIKE', '%$auth_code %'); that time it's are not working

Answer (score 0):

try to used like that

```
$tmsid = 1001;

DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT tmsid, RIGHT(tmsid,6) as max_number FROM tms_tables WHERE tmsid=(SELECT MAX(tmsid) FROM tms_tables where tmsid LIKE :tmid)"),['tmid' => '%'.$tmsid.'%']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using single quotes to both enclose the entire query string as well as enclose the field in the query. You should use the query builder to its full capacity instead and let laravel deal with things like preparing statements:

```
DB::table('tms_tables')
    ->select('tmsid', DB::raw('RIGHT(tmsid, 6) as max_number'))
    ->where('tmsid', function ($query) {
         $query->selectRaw('MAX(tmsid')
               ->from('tms_tables as tms_tables_inner')
               ->where('tmsid', 'LIKE', '%1001%');
     });
```

This should create a functionally equivalent query to what you have

Comment: It's working but when i use 'LIKE', '%1001%'  variable replace to 1001 and  $auth_dept_code = Auth::user()->dept_code;
$auth_branch_code = Auth::user()->branch_code;
$auth_code = $auth_dept_code.$auth_branch_code; $auth_code is 1001,   variable ->where('tmsid', 'LIKE', '%$auth_code %');  that time it's are not working

Comment: put it in double quotes if you want PHP to actually eveluate the variable e.g. `"%$auth_code%"`

Comment: same problem not working. but the static variable is working